# How to populate a reactjs form using database content?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to setup an edit form as part of a CRUD page (the Update section), using the following method to get a row from the relevant database table:

Line for creating each row on the Display table - 
`` <Link className="btn btn-info btn-sm float-right" to={`/dashboard/clients/${row.ClientID}`}><GoPencil/></Link> ``

The state setup and componentdidmount for the edit page -

```
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            ClientName: '',
            FirstName: '',
            LastName: '',
            ClientEmail: '',
            ClientPhone: '',
            Active: '',
            errors: {}
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleRegister = this.handleRegister.bind(this)
    }

componentDidMount(){
    const clientID = this.props.match.params.id
    const Client = 'localhost:8082/api/clients:' + clientID;
    this.state = Client;

}
```

I'm trying to update the state for the edit page to be equal to the data called from the api/clients with the right clientID, is there some logical component/aspect I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, it seems to me you are missing the part of making the actual api request and then setting the state with the response.

If this is the case, your `componentDidMount` should look more like this:

```
 async componentDidMount() {
    const clientID = this.props.match.params.id;
    const endpoint = "localhost:8082/api/clients:" + clientID;


    //for the example I'm using the native fetch api, but the pattern should be the same with any REST client (axios, etc,) you choose to use.
    const response = await fetch(endpoint);
    const client = await response.json();

    this.setState(client);
  }
```

Comment: ```./src/pages/UpdateClient.js
Syntax error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function (26:22)```

Response I got but I understand what you're setting up, I may need to fix up some imports or other components elsewhere in my project to get this working.

Comment: yes, you need to add `async` before `componentDidMount` (look at my example) - did you do this?

Comment: Added that, now I'm getting a network error when attempting to fetch resource but at least this is more responsive than blank fields. Feels like it's the right track.